# Appfuse does not show unicode characters properly

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, appfuse

I am developing appfuse modular application in idea with tomcat 7.
But after adding my new locale, -means fa for Persian- Persian character does not showing properly.

In my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
  <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>native2ascii-utf8</id>
   <goals>
   <goal>native2ascii</goal>
   </goals>
  <configuration>
  <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
  <includes>
   <include>ApplicationResources_zh*.properties</include>
   <include>ApplicationResources_ko*.properties</include>
   <include>ApplicationResources_fa*.properties</include>
   <include>displaytag_zh*.properties</include>
   <include>displaytag_fa*.properties</include>
   <include>errors_zh*.properties</include>
   <include>errors_ko*.properties</include>
   <include>errors_fa*.properties</include>
   </includes>
  </configuration>
 </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

first line of taglibs.jsp that included in all of my jsp files:

```
<%@ page language="java" errorPage="/error.jsp" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

but where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem resolved!

```
<%@ page language="java" errorPage="/error.jsp" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

I was added above tag in my `common/taglibs.jsp` file and include it in my jsp files with this command:

```
<%@ include file="/common/taglibs.jsp" %>
```

So this tag not importable, and should be used directly in every jsp file!

Sorry for my bad English.